# Store NSUserDefault in keychain

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, credentials, keychain

In my app I need to store an username and a password. I know this data is sensitive. So I would like to store it in the keychain.
The problem is that the credentials are set up in the iOS settings (NSUserDefault).
Is there any way to store this sensitive data in the keychain using the iOS settings??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15452847/keychain-secure-data-storage

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to read the values in the NSUserDefaults you can then save to keychain pretty easily : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there is only one solution. I'm going to create my own settings view.
Thanks to all!